# OverflowError: math range error

Tags: python, math

```
>>> import math
>>> math.pow(2, 3000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: math range error
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 18):

Use the built-in operator.

```
2**3000
```